# Yii 2 GridView - set options for filter input field(s)

Tags: php, yii2

As I've read the documents and tried everything, there's no way to add an `input-sm` HTML/Bootstrap class to the filter input fields of the `GridView` widget in Yii 2.

One thing I can do is to use `jQuery`, search for those elements and add them an `input-sm` class.

Is there a way to achive this in Yii 2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible, there is `filterInputOptions` for that in [DataColumn](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-datacolumn.html#$filterInputOptions-detail) class.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    // ...
    'columns' => [
        // ...
        [
            'attribute' => 'name',
            'filterInputOptions' => [
                'class' => 'form-control input-sm', 
                'id' => null
            ],
        ]
    ],
]) ?>
```